# Prove an $M \times M$ matrix has $M-1$ zero eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $b$ be an $M \times 1$ complex vector and matrix $R = {{\alpha}^2}{b}{b^t}$.

Prove that $R$ has $(M - 1)$ zero eigenvalues and that the distinct eigenvector of $R$ with non-zero eigenvalue is $b$.

Comment: This assumes $\alpha \neq 0$ and $b \neq \vec{0}$.  It is best for your to show your thoughts.  For this problem, you just need to show there are $M-1$ linearly independent vectors $v_k$, $k \in \{1, ..., M-1\}$, that satisfy $Rv_k=\vec{0}$.

Comment: What is $\;\alpha\;$ ? is $\;b^H\;$ to mean $\;b^T=$ the transpose of $\;b\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio $H$ is often used for the "Hermitian transpose" (conjugate transpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$b=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix}\implies b^H=( \overline x\; \overline y\; \overline z\; \overline w)$$

and thus

$$bb^H=\begin{pmatrix}
|x|^2&x \overline y&x \overline z&x \overline w\\
  \overline xy&|y|^2&y \overline z&y \overline w\\
 \overline xz& \overline  yz&|z|^2&z \overline w\\
 \overline xw& \overline yw& \overline zw&|z|^2\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, call the above matrix's rows $\;c_1,...c_4\;$ resp. , and then observe that

$$c_2=\frac yxc_1\;,\;\;c_3=\frac zxc_1\;,\;\;c_4=\frac wxc_1$$

(what happens if $\;x=0\;$ ?) , so that we get that rank$\,bb^H=1\;$ , and thus there are three linearly independent vectors $\;u_i\;,\;\;i=1,2,3\;$ such that $\;bb^Hu_i=0\;$.

Finally, check directly that

$$Rb=\alpha^2 bb^Hb=\alpha^2(|x|^2+|y^2+|z|^2+|w|^2)b$$

and assuming $\;\alpha\neq0\;$ there we have our eigenvector for our non-zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Calculate $R^2$ and see how it relates to $R$. What does this tell you about the minimal polynomial of $R$. Then show that $R$ has rank $1$ by inspecting the rowspace of $R$. What do you know about projections of rank $1$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Any (non-zero) vector orthogonal to $b$ is an eigenvector of $R$.  $b$ is itself *also* an eigenvector of $R$.  With this, we have accounted for $M$ eigenvalues.